# How to display the Parent next child rows in SQl server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to rearrange the parent row next child rows in sql server like below

```
Rownum name parentid
--------------------

1     sathish null

2     kumar   null

3     sk      1

4     sk      1

5     sk      2
```

now i want to rearrange like below

```
Rownum name parentid
--------------------
1      sathish  null

3      sk       1

4      sk       1

2      kumar    null

5      sk       2
```

pls help with sql query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
Declare @t table(Rownum int, name varchar(100),parentid int)
insert into @t values (1,'sathish', null),(2,'kumar',null)
,(3,'sk',1),(4,'sk',1),(5,'sk',2)

;WiTH CTE as
(
 select *,rank()over( order by rownum) rn from @t where parentid is null
),
CTE1 as
(
select * from CTE
union all

select a.*,b.rn from CTE1 B 
inner join @t a on a.parentid=b.Rownum
where a.parentid is not null

)
select * from cte1 order by  rn
```

Answer (score 0):

check THIS IT WILL WORK

```
SELECT *
FROM YOURTABLE 
ORDER BY COALESCE(parentid ,Rownum ),Rownum
```

Comment: you could just order by instead of group by `ORDER BY COALESCE(parentid ,Rownum ),Rownum`

Comment: You should use `ORDER BY`, not `GROUP BY`. This just happens to be ordering the records in that order for now, but you cannot guarantee an order without `ORDER BY`

Comment: I think HERE group by will also functions like order by .....  but tanq gentleman.....

Comment: Definitely not. Group By is completely different to order by. It's a fact: you cannot guarantee an order without `ORDER BY`

Comment: yes I agree with you but sometimes it may or may not produce the same result as the order by gives

Comment: `GROUP BY` sometimes works. `ORDER BY` always works. I'd choose the code the always works.